# Why does my blower motor not activate when called for fan or AC but the induction motor does spin intermittently?

Tags: hvac

[image]I had a clogged condensation pipe which lead to water all over my unit. Once repaired I turned the fan/ac back on and the blower motor would not engage, the board was clicking from the relay and the heater induction motor would turn for a few seconds and then the breaker would trip. I changed the blower motor and capacitor with no change. Then I changed the board and transformer and I get the same result except the breaker does not trip just keeps trying to turn on the induction motor and not the blower. I then tried to turn on the heater and it immediately tripped the breaker.

It is an American Standard Freedom 80 horizontal. The original blower motor was an Emerson model K55HXDJM-7081enter image description here

Comment: It sounds to me like either there's still moisture in there somewhere, or you haven't yet replaced all the failed components. If you [edit] to include the brand/model of the equipment involved and maybe some pictures, you're more likely to get a specific answer. If you leave us with nothing but a generic "blower motor" you'll only get a generic answer.

Comment: It is an American Standard Freedom 80 horizontal. The original blower motor was an Emerson model K55HXDJM-7081

Comment: Always best to [edit] your post to include that info. Not everyone reads the comments and comments can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! First time on here

Comment: The commands to turn on/off come from thermostat. Do not see your drip pan in that picture. Usually the drip pan is under the electronic so how did the water get there ? Do you have drip pan overflow switch.

Comment: There was water coming out of the top of the evap unit at different spots but mainly dripping off of the blower motor housing down into the cavity under the entire unit. The house has a cement hole that seems act as the drip pan and then exits the house.

Comment: Thank you, strange set up, can you post the photo of the evap coil. As said, newer seen evap coil and the pan above the AC electronics. Since you replaced all known relevant parts, what is blowing the fuse ?